# Grouping pandas data by descending column values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to group my pandas dataframe such that the following dataframe:

```
  datePublished quarter   ratio  periodNumber
0    2020-04-26      Q1    236.5           1.0
1    2020-01-26      Q4    171.1           4.0
2    2019-10-27      Q3    149.2           3.0
3    2019-07-28      Q2    180.6           2.0
4    2019-04-28      Q1    224.1           1.0
5    2019-01-27      Q4    172.6           4.0
6    2018-10-28      Q3     78.1           3.0
7    2018-07-29      Q2    156.0           2.0
8    2018-04-29      Q1    125.3           1.0
9    2018-01-28      Q4    138.3           4.0
```

Will become grouped:

```
  datePublished quarter   ratio  periodNumber
0    2020-04-26      Q1    236.5           1.0
```

---

```
1    2020-01-26      Q4    171.1           4.0
2    2019-10-27      Q3    149.2           3.0
3    2019-07-28      Q2    180.6           2.0
4    2019-04-28      Q1    224.1           1.0
```

---

```
5    2019-01-27      Q4    172.6           4.0
6    2018-10-28      Q3     78.1           3.0
7    2018-07-29      Q2    156.0           2.0
8    2018-04-29      Q1    125.3           1.0
```

---

```
9    2018-01-28      Q4    138.3           4.0
```

Notice that the periodNumber column should be in a continuous descending order.
I had no luck so far. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign labels to the grouped periods using `shift` and `cumsum`:

```
df["category"] = ((df["quarter"] == "Q4") & (df[["quarter"]].shift()["quarter"]=="Q1")).cumsum()
```

Then you can `groupby` `df["category"]`:

```
df.groupby('category')
```

Result:

```
  datePublished quarter  ratio  periodNumber   B  category
0    2020-04-26      Q1  236.5             1  Q1         0


  datePublished quarter  ratio  periodNumber   B  category
1    2020-01-26      Q4  171.1             4  Q4         1
2    2019-10-27      Q3  149.2             3  Q3         1
3    2019-07-28      Q2  180.6             2  Q2         1
4    2019-04-28      Q1  224.1             1  Q1         1


  datePublished quarter  ratio  periodNumber   B  category
5    2019-01-27      Q4  172.6             4  Q4         2
6    2018-10-28      Q3   78.1             3  Q3         2
7    2018-07-29      Q2  156.0             2  Q2         2
8    2018-04-29      Q1  125.3             1  Q1         2


  datePublished quarter  ratio  periodNumber   B  category
9    2018-01-28      Q4  138.3             4  Q4         3
```

Comment: The question is absolutely fine. Sometime questions are downvoted if no attempt to solve the issue is shown in the question.

Comment: Great! @RJ Adriaansen. I attempted a lot with cumsum, shift and groupby but was unable to produce it myself. So asking the question directly felt more straightforward. Once again, thank you!